# Remote Include in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I saw a post from a user :

> Since many users can not modify apache configurations or use htaccess
>   files, the best way to avoid unwanted access to include files would be
>   a line at the beginning of the include-file:
>
> `<?php if (!defined('APPLICATION')) exit; ?>`
>
> And in all files that are allowed to be called externally:
>
> `<?php define('APPLICATION', true); ?>`
>
> ```
>  Balu
> ```

I do not know why we have to do this when we can set allow_url_include = false in php.ini

Also a hacker can define APPLICATION at it is own script and use the php script .

Do you know what he means about htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not about someone “hacking” your server, but someone simple requesting `http://example.com/includes/foo.php` – if you don’t want that include file to do anything or output anything when accessed directly – and you have no means to disable HTTP access to that directory via server config – then you can use the described approach to have it exit immediately if it was not accessed via include in any of your own scripts that defined that constant.